# Count number of clients connected to a server using TCP/IP socket in C programming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have to count the number of clients connected to my server using mutex and TCP/IP sockets in C programming.

This is my `server.c` source file:

```
int numberOfClientsConnected = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main ()
{
    // ... creation, binding and listen ...

    while (1) {

        clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddress, &addrSize);


        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        numberOfClientsConnected++;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        child = fork();

        if (child == 0) {

            close(serverSocket);

            while (1) {
                recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);

                if (strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0) {
                    printf("%s:%d left\n", inet_ntoa(newAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddress.sin_port));
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

                    numberOfClientsConnected--;

                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

                    break;
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s:%d wrote: %s\n", inet_ntoa(newAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddress.sin_port), buffer);
                    printf("There are %d client(s) connected\n", numeroDiClientAttualmenteConnessi);
                    // Invio del messaggio
                    send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    close(clientSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in my screenshot:

[image: Console messages]

If I check the number of clients connected from client1 it will always display me "1"; if I check with client2 it will always display me "2". That is number of clients connected depends on from which client I text. What's the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` creates a new process, not a new thread. Variables are not shared between processes. Your child process gets a copy of the variable and only sees the value of the variable as it was when it was forked.